# Javascript - how to animate scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was only able to get a div on click into view with the `scrollIntoView` function, and it works as it should, just the way I want it, but I wonder is there a way to somehow animate it, and make it a bit slower?

I have tried with a suggestion from [here](https://praveenlobo.com/blog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/):

```
function scroll(element, parent){
      $(parent)[0].scrollIntoView(false);
      $(parent).animate({
         scrollTop: $(parent).scrollTop() + $(element).offset().top - $(parent).offset().top,
         duration: 500,
         easing: 'swing'
       });
    }
```

But it pushes the element to far up, it is not pushing it as it is on just:

```
$('#drawer')[0].scrollIntoView(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scroll = function(element, parent, time) {
   $(parent).animate({
       scrollTop: $(element)[0].offsetTop - $(parent)[0].offsetTop,
   }, time, "swing");
}
```

You might want to add `scrollIntoView`, i don't know what that is for.
This works in jQuery 3.1.1 .

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
Lots of options, I've used it several times with good results.

Comment: I tried using it by just adding cdn link and calling it like so `$('#drawer').scrollTo(92, 500);`  but I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollTo is not a function(…)`

Comment: I see, there's an error with the latest jQuery version. Using jquery 2.2.4 it works. I have notified the author.

Comment: Also, it should be called $(container).scrollTo( element, time)